# Apache POI - Skip a word page with a specific word

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm reading a word file with `Apache POI`, I would like to skip a page in the word file when it reads a specific  word like `Colofon`.

I have a little starting point with :

`if(run.getText().equals("Colofon"))`

The question I have is what do I have to put in the `if statement`?
I tried `run.addBreak.PAGE` but this just puts the entire page one down.

Comment: Might be surprising but page is not mainly document structuring element in Word, except there are explicit page breaks set. If not explicit page breaks are set, then a Word document consists of a stream of elements like paragraphs, tables, pictures, ... which are floaring dynamically over the pages. So detecting what will be on one page is not as easy as it sounds before Word has rendered the document. So first question is, **are** explicit page breaks set or not?

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. I will have look into explicit page breaks wether they are set or not.